# Inversion in the formal power series ring

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, power-series

In my lecture a (commutative algebra) theorem was given without proof:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $p\in R[[x]]$ such that $p(0)=0$. Then we have

> $\exists q\in R[[x]]:p(q(x))=q(p(x))=x\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad p'(0)\in R^{\times}.$

Since I have not seen a proof I am interested in references about this. So who knows some books/papers/...?

Thank you.

Comment: This is in one respect an overstatement.  If the assumption $p(0)=0$ were to frame the highlighted statement, it would be sound.  However consider a formal power series $p(X) = X+1$.  Clearly there exists $q(X) = X-1$ such that $p(q(X)) = q(p(X)) = X$, but $p(0) = 1 \neq 0$.

Comment: So how would you formulate this theorem? Like this it seems wrong. Maybe I change the $\Leftrightarrow$ to a $\Leftarrow$.

Comment: You could change it that way, but it you want to work in the reverse implication, put the assumption $p(0) = 0$ *ahead* of the highlighted statement.  If you like, I will so edit (it will have little or no effect on the validity of what you accepted as an answer).

Comment: You can edit it if you want of course. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a variant of the following famous result:

> **Theorem** (*Hensel's Lemma*): Let $S$ be an $I$-adically complete commutative ring, $f\in S[T]$ and $\xi\in S$ such that $f(\xi)\equiv 0$ modulo $I$ (i.e. $\xi$ is an 'approximate' zero of $f$) and $f^{\prime}(\xi)\in (S/I)^\times$. Then there exists a unique $\tilde{\xi}$ such that $\xi\equiv\tilde{\xi}$ modulo $I$ such that $f(\xi)=0$.

*Proof:* This can be proved by mimicking [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), with convergence ensured by $I$-completeness.

Now, in the above formulation, $p$ is (necessarily) a polynomial and not a power series, but if you restrict the evaluation function to elements of $I$, you can allow $f\in S[[T]]$ and interpret it as an operator $I\to I$. This results in a well-posed question which is again answered affirmatively by Newton's Method.

To get to your problem, apply the theorem in the following context: $$S:=R[[x]], \quad I := (x),\quad \xi:=0,\quad\text{ and }\quad f := p(T) - x\in R[[x]][[T]]$$
Note that $x$ is interpreted as a constant term here. The assumptions of the theorem are met, $$f(0) = -x\in I\quad\text{ and }\quad f^{\prime}(0) = p^{\prime}(0)\in R^{\times}\subset R[[x]]^{\times},$$ so we conclude the existence of $q\in (x)\subset R[[x]]$ such that $f(q)=0$, i.e. $p(q) = x$.

Finally, comparing the coefficients of $x$ in $p(q)=x$ shows that $p^{\prime}(0)q^{\prime}(0)=1$, so $q$ satisfies the same hypothesis as $p$. This shows that $\{p\in x R[[x]]\ |\ p^{\prime}(0)\in R^{\times}\}$ is a group under substitution, with unit element $x$, and the uniqueness of inverses shows that $p(q)=x$ implies $q(p)=x$, too.

Comment: @user114179: You're welcome :)

Comment: 1) "q  satisfies the same hypothesis as q" ?  2) In any case, my question is the iff part.  Take f(0)=0 with resulting p(0) != 0 ; but then p(q(x))=q(p(x))=x ; thus we have p such that p(0) !=0 but it has an inverse.  So the iff fails.

Comment: @rrogers (1) Corrected, thank you! (2) Note that it's a standing assumption throughout the question and answer that all power series have vanishing constant term.

Comment: Your right... given the hypothesis, iff is correct.  I have been looking at proving all of the different Lagrange formulations in Formal Power Series are equivalent in Isabelle and overlooked p(0)=0 above.  In some papers people make universal declarations but the function p(x)=1-x and q(y)=1-y shows that _sometimes_ p(0)!=0 and q(0)!=0 can be compositional inversion pairs.  I _think_, I am still working my way through.  I follow your later reasoning but don't know anything about "I-adically complete commutative ring" so I am left out of being able to apply it like you did.

Comment: @rrogers Oh, that's very interesting to hear that you are formalizing this in Isabelle. I've been working a lot with Coq lately. Anyway, $I$-adically complete means completeness of $R$ with respect to the topology in which the powers $I^n$ are the neighbourhood base of $0$ - so for $I=(x)$ in the power series ring it means e.g. that a series of power series is Cauchy if and only if each fixed coefficient is eventually constant, and then there's a canonical notion of limit of such a sequence.

Comment: @rrogers I'm happy to provide more information, but to begin, I'm sure you'll find a lot by searching the web and/or looking at commutative algebra textbooks.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I have looked at some p-adic explanations and realized I had to spend _some_ time before I internalized the reasoning.  I do, mostly, understand the Cauchy process.  Any online accessible sources for I-adic/p-adic would be appreciated.  I don't understand what you meant by I-adic though.  By "coefficients" do you mean real's or rational's converging?  Or sequences of sequences; or some such?